# Which wait mechanism is Polly using

Tags: polly

`Polly` has several retry functionalities like for example `WaitAndRetryForever`. I looked in the documentation but couldn't find what is used exactly for making the thread wait until the next retry. I guess `Polly` uses [System.Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) for this or is it something completely different? Thanks for any collaboration.

Comment: Does the question concern synchronous or asynchronous executions?

Comment: Both, I just want to know how Polly works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asynchronous executions (`fooAsyncPolicy.ExecuteAsync(...)`) [wait with `Task.Delay(...)`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/1f0de43a9991cdc93b6d5fbcff2b37cf96eec0c2/src/Polly.Shared/Utilities/SystemClock.cs#L25), freeing the thread the caller was using while the delay occurs.

---

Synchronous executions (`fooSyncPolicy.Execute(...)`) wait between retries [in a cancellable thread-blocking manner](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/1f0de43a9991cdc93b6d5fbcff2b37cf96eec0c2/src/Polly.Shared/Utilities/SystemClock.cs#L18).  This means that, for the synchronous (a):

```
action();
```

compared to the synchronous (b):

```
policy.Execute(action);
```

the following three things all hold:

1. both (a) and (b) block progress from continuing (subsequent code does not run) until the statement has completed;
2. (b) executes `action` on the same thread that (a) originally would have;
3. (b) expresses exceptions (if Policy operation does not intervene) in the same/similar-as-possible way that (a) originally would have.

These semantics (1) (2) (3) are intentional, to keep synchronously executing code with Polly as similar in semantics/behaviour (surrounding code needs little adjustment) as executing code without Polly.

---

Anticipating a follow-up question: Wouldn't it be possible to write the synchronous Polly: `Policy.Handle<T>().WaitAndRetry(...).Execute(action)` so that it didn't block a thread while waiting before retrying?:  Yes, but no solution has been found that is preferable to letting the caller control transitions to TPL `Task`s or `async`/`await` and then using Polly's `ExecuteAsync(...)`.